# when the Checkbox is True Hide the Whole Row included Fields in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm new in PowerApps and I'm trying to hide a row from a list when the checkbox is true and leave visible when false.

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property manually to your data, say a boolean named *Hide*.
This way, then you can perform a filter: `Filter(<yourdata>, Hide <> true)`.

To add your column: `ClearCollect(NewCol,AddColumns(OldCol,"Hide",false));`

This way, when you click on the checkbox, it's *OnChange* event could change *ThisItem*'s value to make it disappear from the list. The data is still there, though. It just won't show it in the table/gallery anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with the hidden values. I'm assuming all checkbox values are `true` upon import.

**Mock data:**

```
ClearCollect(colTasks,
    {check: true, taskName: "task1 ZI rep1", desc: "", startDate: "19/05/2022", assignedTo: "Bob", dueDate: "31/05/2022"},
    {check: true, taskName: "task2 ZI rep2", desc: "", startDate: "01/05/2022", assignedTo: "Sally", dueDate: "28/05/2022"},
    {check: true, taskName: "task3 ZI rep1", desc: "", startDate: "16/05/2022", assignedTo: "Sam", dueDate: "17/05/2022"},
    {check: true, taskName: "task4 ZI rep1", desc: "", startDate: "01/06/2022", assignedTo: "Smithy", dueDate: "05/06/2022"},
    {check: true, taskName: "task5 ZI rep2", desc: "", startDate: "18/05/2022", assignedTo: "Joe", dueDate: "31/05/2022"},
    {check: true, taskName: "task6 ZI rep1", desc: "", startDate: "15/05/2022", assignedTo: "Billy Bob", dueDate: "03/06/2022"},
    {check: true, taskName: "task7 ZI rep2", desc: "", startDate: "03/05/2022", assignedTo: "Bobby Sue", dueDate: "25/05/2022"}
)
```

**Try this:**

1. Add the following to the `OnUncheck` property of the Checkbox:

```
// Changes the checkbox value to `false`

Patch(
    colTasks,
    ThisItem,
    {
        check: false
    }
);

//Collects the record in another collection in case you need it

Collect(colRemovedTasks, ThisItem);

//Removes the record from the current collection

RemoveIf(colTasks, check = false)
```

Then you can have another Gallery control where the users can pick which ones to add back!

- Just chance the collection name and paste the above code on the second Checkboxes `OnUnselect` property

**Illustration:**

[image]